# Subversion - Branch of a branch

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I would like to do exactly as the subject says.  It's not possible to merge the current branch to the trunk yet, otherwise, that's what I'd do.  The subbranch (or whatever the term is) will be merged with the branch and then the branch back to the trunk.

Theoretically, this should work - does anyone see any problems with this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that sounds perfectly fine to me.

The only time you *might* have a problem is if you tried to merge the child branch directly into the trunk.

Comment: I don't see any problem merging the child branch directly to trunk. the only problem might be if you want to merge the child to trunk and *later* merge the parent branch to trunk - I don't expect this to go down well.

Comment: I just quickly tried this myself on a local repository and a trivial example. Using --reintegrate to collapse the branches back again worked fine.

Comment: Let's say I've got this setup: trunk -> branch1 -> branch2, and I first want to reintegrate branch1 into trunk and continue develop branch2, merging changes from trunk (instead of branch1 since that's gone). Then later reintegrate branch2 into trunk. My tests indicates trouble with this. Any experience?